# How to change the UI font in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I can change the editor font easily in the settings menu. However, I can not change the menu and other UI related font.

Is there is way to change the UI fonts in PyCharm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click `File -> Settings`

[image]

Then go to the  `-> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance` section

Then, adjust the setting:

`Override default fonts by (not recommended):`

[image]

Comment: Why is this "not recommended"?

Comment: Changing the UI font may break some interface elements depending on the font/size you specify. You can go ahead and change it, but there is a chance it may not look perfect.